# Angular 2 download pdf using webapi C#.net

Tags: angular

I have Angular 2 and web API application, I am trying to download pdf using Web API. Below is the sample code. When I click on download button a get request is sent to web API which in response send file stream, typescript converts this stream to PDF. But when I opens this PDF it shows me below error - "Adobe reader could not open file beacause it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged".

Code : WebAPI

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetReportPDF1(int ProjectID)
{
    string htmlContents = reportHTML.BuildHTMLDoc(ProjectID);
    byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlContents);
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(temp)
    };

   result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

   result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
             new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
             {
                 FileName = "Report.pdf"
             };

        return result;
    }
```

Code : component.ts

```
GenarateReportPDF() {           
    var ProjectID = localStorage.getItem('ProjectID');
    this._reportService.getReportPDF()
    .subscribe(
        response => { 
        var blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var filename = 'file.pdf';
        filesaver. saveAs(blob, filename);
       },
        error => {
            console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    )
}
```

Code : Service.ts

```
getReportPDF(): Observable<any> {
    var ProjectID = localStorage.getItem('ProjectID');

    return this._http.get("http://localhost:52719/api/Report/GetReportPDF?ProjectID=" +ProjectID, 
                    { responseType:   ResponseContentType.Blob })
                    .map(res => res.blob())                      
}
```

Comment: Are you able to just download the file using the browser and the link and actually open the pdf file? Reading your code, I see you are creating HTML content but trying to open it as a PDF.

Comment: The problem is more Adobe issue that on your code. [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-error-1015-11001-update.html)

Comment: Yes I am able to download the pdf file succcefully but when I open pdf it shows an error. Actually I am trying to create pdf file using html content.